# document.documentElement used in "in" statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw this piece of code in jQuery's source. I am a novice in javascript and I would like to know how this works.

```
if ( "getBoundingClientRect" in document.documentElement ) {
// do something...
}
```

How is it different from

```
if(document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect) {
// do something...
}
```

...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an expression using the [`in` operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.7). The `in` operator checks to see if the target object has a property with the given name (directly, or via the object's prototype).

What it's doing is seeing if `document.documentElement` has a property with the name `getBoundingClientRect` (which is a handy function jQuery would like to use if the browser provides it).

> How is it different from `if(document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect) { // do something... }`

`in` doesn't require fetching the *value* of the property, just checking that it exists. Also note that the second form you list would test the truthiness of the *value* of the property. In the case of a function like `getBoundingClientRect` that would be fine, but if you wanted to test something whose value might come back falsey (`0`, `""`, etc.), it would fail even though the property exists.

You'll see this sort of thing a lot when doing feature-detection. For instance, if you want to know if a browser supports the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute:

```
if ('placeholder' in document.createElement('input')) {
    // Yes, it does
}
```

This is an example where we couldn't use the form `if (document.createElement('input').placeholder)` because if the condition were false, we wouldn't know whether it was false because the property didn't exist, or false because the property existed but had a falsey value (and the default value for `placeholder` is `""`, which is indeed falsey).

[Gratuitous link to list of feature detections.](https://github.com/kangax/cft)

Comment: @GauthamRenganathan: Good deal, glad that helped.

Answer (score 3):

from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)
The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object.

syntax :

```
prop in objectName
```

prop
    A string or numeric expression representing a property name or array index.

objectName : Name of an object.

so `document.documentElement` is the Object  and `"getBoundingClientRect"` is the property.

Answer (score 2):

The `'a' in obj` is different from `obj.a` if `a == false`.

```
obj = {a: false};
'a' in obj;
> true
obj.a
> false
```

Answer (score 1):

The `in` operator checks to see if a given property is or present within a specified object or not. *SO,*

```
if ( "getBoundingClientRect" in document.documentElement ) {
// do something...
}
```

will check if `getBoudingClientRect` property is available in `document.documentElement` Object.

Moreover, you might want to read the [article](http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/) form John Resig himself, who has well explained, Why it is used.